# How can I destructure data props more than 2 levels deeper in a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an react-apollo HoC wrapped component and data fetched from github graphql api.

say our wrapped component props will have data that looks like this:

[image]

how do I get to edges by desctructuring??

I know i can get to the `search` field like this:

`({ data: { search }} ) => <Component data={search.edges} />`

but is something like this possible?

`({ data: { search: { edges} }} ) => <Component data={edges} />`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and you've answered your own question, this is correct:

```
({ data: { search: { edges} }}) => <Component data={edges} />
```

Your `Component` will now get your `edges` array as a prop named `data`

Comment: this refuses to work...i get "cannot read property 'edges' of undefined"
and it references this exact line ->
```({ data: { loading, error, search: { edges }}}) => <Component data={edges} />```

Comment: Try replacing data with variables inside of destructuring

Comment: how do you mean @Linas

Comment: @bnovf  ({ variables: { search: { edges} }}) => <Component data={edges} />